# Comentario en bash

Tags: ionic, bash

Tengo una aplicación Ionic v1, donde tengo algunos hooks para trabajar con gulp. El hook es :

```
#!/bin/bash
gulp dev
```

Cuando hago un `ionic run android` recibo el error

> "bash" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
>   programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
>   Error: Hook failed with error code 1: ...hooks\before_run\all_before_run.sh

Cuando saco la linea `#!/bin/bash` todo funciona bien.

Se supone que estando con `#` es solo un comentario y deberia ignorarse... Pero por que falla?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Si bien es un comentario, es lo que se conoce como ["shebang"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang). En el mundo unix/linux es la forma de definir el path al interprete del script en cuestión. En tu caso, el error seguramente te está diciendo que `bash` no está alojado en `/bin`, seguramente estará en otra carpeta, cada sistema puede tenerlo en distintas carpetas, podrías averiguar la misma haciendo `which bash`, no sería raro que hubiera más de uno en el sistema. Al quitar esta línea seguramente se está invocando al `bash` que pudiera estar configurado en el `path` del sistema. Yo diría que no se la quites y  la reemplaces por esta otra:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Que básicamente es un poco más portable y que ejecuta el primer `bash` que estuviera en el `path`

Comment: estoy en windows, no me sirve el comando `which bash`, algo similar?

Comment: Ejecute el bash y ahi obtuve la ruta, que es `#!/usr/bin/ bash` quedo solucionado!, gracias!

Comment: Una ultima consulta, cuando pongo `#!/usr/bin/bash` me dice que no puede encontrar la ruta especifica, sin embargo cuando ejecuto el bash, la pestaña dice `/usr/bin/bash --login -i` y si funciona

Comment: Prueba si funciona agregar la línea `#!/usr/bin/env bash` y me cuentas.

Comment: Tampoco funciona con esa linea

Comment: No conozco como trabaja ionic, tampoco desde dónde se ejecuta `all_before_run.sh`, pero si puedes editar el script y le quitas el "shebang" y funciona, podrías agregar la siguiente instrucción `echo $0` eso te debería decir con que shell se está ejecutando el Script cuando no tiene shebang, y de última establecer ese.

Comment: Lo hice, de hecho cuando se ejecuta el script, sale la ruta `usr/bin/bash` pero al dejarlo dentro del .sh no funciona :S

Comment: Es muy raro, tal vez algún problema de salto de línea de DOS. yo probaría si lo tienes disponible correr `dos2unix all_before_run.sh` para dejar los saltos de línea nativos de unix.

Comment: instale otra consola CMDER y funciono todo, no tuve que modificar nada. Creo que la ruta al instalador del GIT estaba incorrecta. Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, si te funcionó cuando eliminaste el shebang (es decir, el #!/bin/bash) es porque:

1. Anda mal tu distro de Linux
2. No estás en alguna distro de Linux.

1) Si anda mal tu distro de Linux puedes ejecutar lo siguiente en tu terminal.

```
$command -v bash  #Para que te muestre lo que entiente tu terminal por "bash"
                  #Puedes copiar esa ruta y ponerla en el shebang.
$cat /etc/shells  #Si no estás seguro de tener bash (lo cual sería rarísimo en tu distro)
                  #Puedes ver qué otros interpretes de comandos tienes con este comando.
```

También puedes correr el script con "source", ".", "bash", "sh". Y ver con cuál de estos corre. "source" y "." son sinónimos y cargan el contenido de un archivo en la terminal en la que estás, en cambio, "bash" es el programa que deberías tener en la ruta "/bin/bash" y "sh" es un enlace simbólico a "/bin/dash".

Teniendo en cuenta eso puedes hacer algo como `$source tu_script`

2) En caso de que no estés en una distribución de linux (lo cual parece porque el error que copiaste y pegaste habla de "archivo por lotes"), instala un emulador (En caso de que quieras jugar con bash para scriptear). Puedes instalar:

- [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html)
- [Git-shell](https://git-scm.com/downloads)
- [Cmder](http://cmder.net/)
- [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)
- WSL (alias "Ubuntu windows") de la Tienda de Microsoft

Ya que lo instales no tendría porque haber problema alguno con ese script.
Sólo sería correrlo con:

```
$bash tu_script
$sh tu_script
```

Para lo cual no es necesario el shebang. En cambio, si quieres correrlo con el shebang, primero hazlo ejecutable con `chmod +x tu_script` y luego corre el programa con:

```
$./tu_script #o en su defecto.
$/ruta/completa/a/tu_script
```

La otra es que quizás no necesitas crear un archivo para bash, sino para bat (que ese si es un archivo de procesamiento por lotes) y ese mismo archivo ponle la extensión .bat, le pones un "pause" al final del código, eliminas el shebang y debería de correr.

Aunque quizás lo mejor (sólo como sugerencia) es que la próxima indiques desde que SO, consola/terminal lo estás corriendo.

Referente a lo del shebang, está relacionado con el funcionamiento de lo llamado números mágicos.

Aquí hay información sobre el shebang:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang

Y aquí sobre los números mágicos:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_m%C3%A1gico_(inform%C3%A1tica)

Pero en resumen, permiten a un usuario correr un programa "como si fuera" un binario, se lee el programa que describe el shebang y se ejecuta el contenido del programa con base en el programa que se describa, puede ser bash, python, cat, awk, ruby, cualquiera del mundo Unix. Y permite identificarlo, por ejemplo, cuando tienes un programa "tu_script" con el shebang "#!/bin/bash" y le pides al comando `file tu_script` que te diga qué tipo de programa es, te devuelve algo de tipo:

```
$file tu_script
tu_script: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```